# Calculating pi via collisions

Tags: python, beginner, time-limit-exceeded, numerical-methods, matplotlib

This code calculates pi via collisions; it asks for a user input of N which determines the mass of the second block. It is fully working, it just takes forever to run when N >= 2. I want to be able have at least N=5 and have a reasonable runtime. The issue is in the velocity and x1, x2 calculation I believe. There are just so many that need to be appended that it takes forever to run and then just as long to append.

My code shows that I have tried to use Numba to speed up the runtime, but that doesn't seem to be helping. I am currently using the RK-4 method to update position, and I previously tried the Verlet method which did not seem to have an affect on the runtime. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numba import jit
import time

start = time.time()

@jit(nopython=True)
def RK4_1(x, vx):
    return vx

@jit(nopython=True)
def RK4_2(x, vx):
    return 0

@jit(nopython=True)
def iterate(x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col):
    k1 = dt*RK4_1(x1, vx1)
    k2 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k1/2, vx1)
    k3 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k2/2, vx1)
    k4 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k3, vx1)
    x1 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

    k1 = dt*RK4_1(x2, vx2)
    k2 = dt*RK4_1(x2 + k1/2, vx2)
    k3 = dt*RK4_1(x2 + k2/2, vx2)
    k4 = dt*RK4_1(x2 + k3, vx2)
    x2 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

    k1 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1)
    k2 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k1/2)
    k3 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k2/2)
    k4 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k3)
    vx1 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

    k1 = dt*RK4_2(x2, vx2)
    k2 = dt*RK4_2(x2, vx2 + k1/2)
    k3 = dt*RK4_2(x2, vx2 + k2/2)
    k4 = dt*RK4_2(x2, vx2 + k3)
    vx2 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

    if x1 < 0:
        x1 = 0
        vx1 = -vx1
        col += 1

    if x2 < x1:
        x2 = x1
        vx1_i = vx1
        vx2_i = vx2
        vx1 = (2*m2*vx2_i + m1*vx1_i - m2*vx1_i)/(m1+m2)
        vx2 = (2*m1*vx1_i + m2*vx2_i - m1*vx2_i)/(m1+m2)
        col += 1

    return x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col

dt = 0.01

m1 = 1
N = int(input("Enter an integer N that will determine the mass of the second block: "))
m2 = 100**N

w1 = 1
w2 = w1*(100**N)**(1/3)
x1 = 1
x2 = 1.15
y1 = 1
y2 = 1
vx1 = 0
vx2 = -1
col = 0

x1arr = np.array([])
x2arr = np.array([])
y1arr = np.array([])
y2arr = np.array([])
vx1arr = np.array([])
vx2arr = np.array([])
colarr = np.array([])

t = 0

while (vx2 < 0) or (abs(vx1) > abs(vx2)):
    x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col = iterate(x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col)
    #print(vx1, vx2)
    t += dt

    x1arr = np.append(x1arr, x1)
    x2arr = np.append(x2arr, x2)
    y1arr = np.append(y1arr, y1)
    y2arr = np.append(y2arr, y2)
    vx1arr = np.append(vx1arr, vx1)
    vx2arr = np.append(vx2arr, vx2)
    colarr = np.append(colarr, col)

print("Number of collisions: %f" % (col))

speed = 1000

def update_plot(i, fig, scat1, scat2, txt):
    last = 0
    if(i>int(len(x1arr)/speed)-2):
        last=1  
    s = int(speed*i)
    scat1.set_data(x1arr[s],y1arr[s])
    scat2.set_data(x2arr[s],y2arr[s])
    #scat.set_sizes(lx1=5, lx2=5*N)
    txt.set_text('x1= %.3f   m1=%.0f\nx2= %.3f   m1=%.0f\nCollisions=%.0f\n t=%.3fs' % (x1arr[s],m1,x2arr[s],m2,colarr[s]+last,(s*dt))) #update of legend
    #print("Frame %d Rendered" % (s))
    return scat1, scat2, txt,

size = 5*N
fig =  plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0, 3]) #animation scale
ax.set_ylim([0,5])
ax.grid()
txt = ax.text(0.05, 0.8, '', transform=ax.transAxes) 
scat1, = ax.plot([], [],'s', c='r', markersize=5) 
scat2, = ax.plot([], [],'s', c='r', markersize=5*(N+1))
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, fargs = (fig, scat1, scat2, txt), frames = int(len(x1arr)/speed), interval = 1, blit=True, repeat=False)
anim.save("originalpi.mp4", fps=30, bitrate=-1)

end = time.time()
print("Total runtime in seconds:  ", end-start)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm confused, can `RK4_1(x, vx)` just be replaced with `vx`? so `k1 = dt*RK4_1(x1, vx1)` is `k1 = dt*vx1`. And `k1 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1)` is `k1 = 0`.

Comment: Yes I believe I could do that, I wrote it this way so that the RK 4 process was visible. Do you think changing it would decrease runtime?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*calculates pi*"? It certainly doesn't print it.

Comment: If you run this code for, say, N=1, an animation will appear that shows the blocks colliding. The number of collisions count out pi. For N=1 the number of collisions is 31, for N=2 it is 314, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am currently using the RK-4 method to update position

Firstly, the naming is unhelpful here. A name like `RK4_1` implies that the method does the quadrature. I think that function is really `dx_dt`, `RK4_2` is really `dvx_dt`, and there would be room to pull out a function like

```
def RK4_step(t, x, dx_dt, dt):
    k1 = dt * dx_dt(x, t)
    k2 = dt * dx_dt(x + k1 / 2, t + dt / 2)
    k3 = dt * dx_dt(x + k2 / 2, t + dt / 2)
    k4 = dt * dx_dt(x + k3, t + dt)
    return x + (1/6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)
```

But secondly, RK4 is completely overkill here. If we inline

> ```
> @jit(nopython=True)
> def RK4_1(x, vx):
>     return vx
>
> @jit(nopython=True)
> def RK4_2(x, vx):
>     return 0
>
> @jit(nopython=True)
> def iterate(x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col):
>     k1 = dt*RK4_1(x1, vx1)
>     k2 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k1/2, vx1)
>     k3 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k2/2, vx1)
>     k4 = dt*RK4_1(x1 + k3, vx1)
>     x1 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
>
>     ...
>
>     k1 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1)
>     k2 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k1/2)
>     k3 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k2/2)
>     k4 = dt*RK4_2(x1, vx1 + k3)
>     vx1 += (1/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
> ```

we get

```
def iterate(x1, x2, vx1, vx2, col):
    x1 += dt*vx1

    ...

    vx1 += 0
```

It seems that it would be *much* quicker to solve simultaneous linear equations to work out when the collision will happen rather than to use quadrature. In fact, [I had a go](https://tio.run/##bZHJboQwDIbveQprpNEkLNOEisuoHHvtqS/AlKCJhk0QKH16aidiUdUcEtn@/HtJ92MfbfO6LLWKoE4gA3yVlEGQslqRXSsIMcJmDEyz8oRkc0KmS7iqNIJYMfbVVmhLZpoS37Jqc8svIVoXwdj3w1QaPvtR3xjgsRIZ1HuBmGRN6dTfQIKuBg2YxRxXTMhRpZgAn0pdcOealSAFhFAA73/yLQ1hGm5lhJnCe4nGQEac74fOvdf50wPYS5gRE2xlseDuSpyLJkaf@iNq5a7pViY3068wXjWp1wObuJ1sduf371pwv3AovYvxbo0VE20D/@1AJJ6IvdBOsK43jeWnj7G@6x7akoapzGDaZrjBuTjBGTi6hFjJ98GaOre6gCmvRk0pnUG0XFFU5tRHAPKaCiGW5Rc), and the actual simulation takes less than a second for `N = 5`.

---

> My code shows that I have tried to use Numba to speed up the runtime, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

The jit is on the wrong parts. I added some debug printing and observed that it slowed down over time, at which point I very quickly spotted the real problem:

> ```
>     x1arr = np.append(x1arr, x1)
>     x2arr = np.append(x2arr, x2)
>     y1arr = np.append(y1arr, y1)
>     y2arr = np.append(y2arr, y2)
>     vx1arr = np.append(vx1arr, vx1)
>     vx2arr = np.append(vx2arr, vx2)
>     colarr = np.append(colarr, col)
> ```

This is copying the entire array every time, so the length of a step is proportional to the number of steps taken.

Solution: use normal lists rather than numpy arrays. numpy is not a panacea: it's good for parallel processing, but that's not what you want here.

**However**, the one advantage that numpy arrays give you here is that they don't have length bounds. In testing with `N = 3` using normal Python lists I got a memory error after slightly more than 245 million steps and 3140 collisions. It might need a 2D structure to handle the large quantities of data. Of course, that doesn't prevent the extremely likely problem of the plot running into memory problems too. A complete structural rethink may be necessary.

---

If you do decide to implement RK4, it's more correct to do a single multi-variable quadrature rather than multiple single-variable ones. Here is where there is a good reason to use numpy arrays. What I mean by multi-variable quadrature is something like

```
k1_x, k1_vx = dt * RK4(x, vx), dt * RK4(vx, ax)
k2_x, k2_vx = dt * RK4(x + k1_x / 2, vx + k1_vx / 2), dt * RK4(vx + k1_vx / 2, ax)
```

etc. (NB For clarity I separated out the variables. For speed you'd put `x` and `vx` in a single numpy array).

---

It makes no sense to start timing before taking the input: the time I take to type `3` and press `Enter` is not really runtime.

---

In terms of general readability, the inline mixing of functions and top-level code is not helpful. It's good to put constants like `dt` at the top, so that when the reader comes to the usage of `dt` in `iterate` they've already seen it. The main loop should probably be a function which returns the arrays (or perhaps a single 2D array) with intermediate values; the plot creation should be a function, and then Python best practice is for the "main" functionality to go at the end with a guard:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(input("Enter an integer N that will determine the mass of the second block: "))
    start = time.time()
    data = generate_collisions(N)
    plot = graph_collisions(data)
    end = time.time()
    print("Total runtime in seconds:  ", end - start)
    plot.show()
```